# What causes this CodePen Google Maps API example to not switch locations correctly on click?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps-api-3

What causes this CodePen Google Maps API example to not switch locations correctly on click?

```
<div id="gmap"></div>    
<div id="menu">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="loc_link" data-lat="12.58" data-long="77.38" data-title="Bangalore" data-html="Bangalore, Karnataka, India">A</a>      
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="loc_link" data-lat="31.2" data-long="121.5" data-title="Shanghai" data-html="Shanghai, China">B</a>      
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="loc_link" data-lat="35.6895" data-long="139.6917" data-title="Tokyo" data-html="Tokyo, Japan">C</a>      
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="loc_link" data-lat="28.6139" data-long="77.2089" data-title="New Delhi" data-html="New Delhi, India">D</a>      
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="loc_link" data-lat="40.7127" data-long="74.0059" data-title="New York" data-html="New York City">E</a>
</div>


$(function(){
var map;
var LocA = [{
        lat: 12.58,
        lon: 77.38,
        title: 'Bangalore',
        html: 'Bangalore, Karnataka, India',
        zoom: 4,
        icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png',
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }];

 map = new Maplace({
    locations: LocA,
    map_div: '#gmap',
    generate_controls: false,
    start: 0   
  }).Load();


$(".loc_link").click(function(){
  var newLoc = [{
        lat: $(this).data('lat'),
        lon: $(this).data('long'),
        title: $(this).data('title'),
        html: $(this).data('html'),
        zoom: 4,
        icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker'+$(this).text()+'.png',
        animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }];
  map.AddLocations(newLoc).Load();
  map.ViewOnMap($(this).index()+1);
});
});
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/invincibleking77/pen/qEGRQq

Sometimes it works fine, and other times, clicking the different location navigation anchors will not switch to the correct address.

I believe this is my first question so thank you for helping me understand if I did not post it in the correct location or if anything else needs to be edited.

I searched quite a bit; however I typically do not find an answer until I know the correct term(s) to use as the query.

Cheers,
Sr.

Answer (score 0):

**The index of markers on the map is not equal to the index of `a.loc_link` you defined**

The index of markers on the map are just defined by the ordering that you created. For example, if you click A > B > C > D > E, then the result is fine, otherwise, index of markers and `a.loc_link` will not match.

The better way to implement (for this plugin) is presetting all locations first.

```js
$(function() {

 var map;
 var Locs = new Array();
 $('a.loc_link').each(function() {
  Locs.push({
   lat: $(this).data('lat'),
   lon: $(this).data('long'),
   title: $(this).data('title'),
   html: $(this).data('html'),
   zoom: 4,
   icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker'+$(this).text()+'.png'
  });
 });

 map = new Maplace({
  locations: Locs,
  map_div: '#gmap',
  generate_controls: false,
  start: 0   
 }).Load();

 $(".loc_link").click(function() {
  map.ViewOnMap($(this).index() + 1);
 });
 
});
```

```css
#gmap{
  width: 70%;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  text-align:center;
}
#menu a.loc_link {
  background: #0f89cf;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu span#tool_tip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry&v=3.13"></script>
<script src="https://maplacejs.com/dist/maplace.min.js"></script>

<div id="gmap"></div>

<div id="menu">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="loc_link" data-lat="12.58" data-long="77.38" data-title="Bangalore" data-html="Bangalore, Karnataka, India">A</a>
  
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="loc_link" data-lat="31.2" data-long="121.5" data-title="Shanghai" data-html="Shanghai, China">B</a>
  
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="loc_link" data-lat="35.6895" data-long="139.6917" data-title="Tokyo" data-html="Tokyo, Japan">C</a>
  
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="loc_link" data-lat="28.6139" data-long="77.2089" data-title="New Delhi" data-html="New Delhi, India">D</a>
  
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="loc_link" data-lat="40.7127" data-long="74.0059" data-title="New York" data-html="New York City">E</a>
  
  <br/>
  <span id="tool_tip">Click links to see effect!</span>
</div>
```